# Yelp or similar dataset needed

Tags: data-request

I am writing a paper on aspect based sentiment analysis and I need appropriate datasets having only positive and negative classes to compare my result to other papers. Two of these papers that have used the yelp dataset:

[Deep Convolutional Neural Network based Approach for Aspect-based Sentiment Analysis](http://onlinepresent.org/proceedings/vol143_2017/41.pdf)
[Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis for Online Reviews](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-10-7605-3_78)

If possible I would like to have access to the datasets they have used, does anyone have them?

Comment: what have you done?

Answer (score -1):

Did you even look @ the PDF's sources?
Data in the first PDF is [clearly linked to its home on Yelp: http://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge](http://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge).

Comment: The data in paper is from previous rounds and not the current round

Comment: where do you say that in your question? "if possible I would like to have access to the datasets they have used"

Comment: Uh its obvious that I am not blind that I can't see the link they have provided and I have mentioned "the data in their paper" and not the website, meaning the data is not in website atm.

Comment: "If possible I would like to have access to the datasets they have used, " yeah really obvious. that literally is the data in the paper. you know what will make me help you more? being rude to me.

Comment: I didn't mean to insult you, however you didn't help. Plus if what I said is insulting, what you have said in answer "Did you even look @ the PDF's sources?" is insulting as well, isn't it?

Comment: dude. your question doesn't say what you have done. and it doesn't clarify anything at all. we get questions like this all day asking us to do their work for them. look at your question and reword it accordingly. had you done that the first time, i wouldn't have wasted my time finding an answer/commenting here.

Comment: this answer is correct my downvoting friends

Comment: Link no longer working?